# Importing .scn file to scene from URL with textures

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I am using ARKit for my application and I try to dynamically load .scn files from web-server

Here is a part of my code

```
    let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.0.31:1234/5a27e09cbad20a7a03ad5d80/box/box.scn")
    if let objectScene = try? SCNScene(url: url!, options: [.overrideAssetURLs: true]) {
        print("load success")
        let node = SCNNode()
        for childNode in objectScene.rootNode.childNodes {
            node.addChildNode(childNode)
        }

        sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
    } else {
        print("error loading")
    }
```

here `box.scn` contains textures. And I got an error

> Failed loading: C3DImage 0x1c00f6f80 src:file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/110F7AB6-00F8-4E5B-B843-46551A23CB7F/ar.app/maps/CMU_Split_Face_Running_200x400_bump.jpg [0.000000x0.000000]

Why Scenekit tries to load this textures from local file ? 
How can I fix it?

Comment: If you set .overrideAssetURLs to TRUE you also should specify .assetDirectoryURLs loading option. But why did you set it to true? The default is False which causes the assets to be loaded relative to the url from where you load the .scn.

Comment: It doesn't work with False either.
The same result !

Comment: @Gor if you fixed this issue please update it.. Thanks

Comment: no I didnt find solution for this issue. Just using local models

Comment: Any update on this issue? Even i am facing the same issue. Is there any way to directly load the .scn file from server with textures without downloading it?

Answer (score 1):

You should download the file along with its textures, and then load the scene. Note that the .scn file and the textures should be in the same directory unless you want to add some loading options.

After downloading a .scn file with a texture from the server, I used this code to display the object:

```
do {
        let scene = try SCNScene(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: "YourDownloadedScnFilePath") , options: nil)

        // Set the scene to the view
        sceneView.scene = scene
    } catch {
        print("ERROR loading scene")
    }
```

Comment: This does not work for me, even though the textures are in the right directory. It looks like SceneKit is looking in the assets instead of the directory.

Comment: I am not seeing this working either. I have the .scn file loading but the textures are not showing as expected. Just white (or colors base), not images that should be there. Any ideas?